# YouTube iFrame API - JavaScript fatal error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

It's not consistent and i don't know how to reproduce but sometimes, just in FireFox, my users are getting the following error in the console:

`TypeError: a.A.g is null`

[image]

From that point the player act weird, not responding to the SDK functionality etc.

Do anyone know this error as well?

Comment: Can you post your code where the error occured? here's the official Google Documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements

Comment: Sorry but no, Its happen internally in YouTube's code without any specific scenario from my side..